# Weird artifact generated by emission shader

Tags: artifacts, emission

I'm not sure what to caption this question but there is a weird artifact that shows up on some frames in my image sequence render. I have a 24 fps config but the animation was too fast so instead of redoing all of the keyframes i decided to do a time remapping of old 100 to new 145. I also use motion blur shutter 0.50 to add some realism. It looks like it has something to do with the plate number/text "McKenzie" object containing an emission shader parented to an empty cube which is also the parent of the car object. And the middle red line-type light below the text and the 2 red back-lights are also emission shaders but part of the car mesh. Any idea what might be the problem or is this normal?

PS: since i found a way to scale the keyframes, i tried again without doing time remapping and still get the same artifacts. I'm using Eevee renderer because Cycles doesn't render clean. I have an old GTX Titan video card.
[image]

Comment: Could you share the file? It doesn't need to be the whole scene, just the road and the plate would be fine, if they are the source of the problem.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka hi thank you for your response and helping me out on this! i uploaded the blender file, a sample frame with the problem is on frame 248 https://pasteall.org/blend/751905a8f4924fdea4905909b795469b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase Steps to 2 or more to give more Motion Blur accuracy.

1. Go to Render property tab.
2. Expand Motion Blur section.
3. Increase Steps to 2.

[image: Render result]

Comment: nice! cool it really worked! thank you very much!